# PHP find string value and marked it by position in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
array:32 [▼
  "ID" => "7917"
  "ProvinceCode" => "MB"
  "Create" => "2016-05-18 18:16:26.790"
  "DayOfTheWeek" => "4"
  "Giai1" => "28192"
  "Giai2" => "83509"
  "Giai3" => "51911-02858"
  "Giai4" => "14102-97270-96025-08465-89047-45904"
  "Giai5" => "7892-9140-4069-8499"
  "Giai6" => "6117-7471-5541-9119-4855-0566"
  "Giai7" => "843-860-023"
  "Giai8" => "71-13-55-89"
  "Giai9" => ""
  "Status" => "1"
]
```

I have a int variable `$position = 59`, and my job is find value by counting characters from `Giai1 to Giai9` for `59 times` count from `0` and get value of this position not include character `-`, so if `$position = 59` then the getted value at position `58` will return.

For example, find value at position `20`, the return is `1 at 14102 in Giai4 (actually 19 count from 0)`

I've been wrote this code to do this

```
$position = 59;
$count = 0;
foreach ($data['result'][0] as $key => $item)
    {
        if(preg_match('@Giai@s', $key))
        {
            $_item = str_replace('-', '', $item);
            $count = $count + strlen($_item);

            $chars = str_split($item);
            $chars_sp = array_count_values($chars);

            $countChar = count($chars);
            if($count > $position)
            {
                //this block contains needed position
                $math = $count - $position;
                $secmath = strlen($_item) - $math;
                for($i=$secmath;$i>=0;$i--){
                    if($chars[$i] == '-'){
                        $splash_last++;
                    }
                }

                $secmath = $secmath + $splash_last;
                if($chars[$secmath] == '-'){
                    echo "+1 - ";
                    $secmath = $secmath + 1;
                }

                echo "Count: $count Match: $math Secmatch: $secmath Splash_last: $splash_last";
                $chars[$secmath] = 'x' . $chars[$secmath] . 'y';

                $edited = implode('', $chars);
                $data['result'][0][$key] = $edited;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    dd($data['result'][0]);
}
```

Expected result will return this array with the mark of getted number. 
For example, code found number at position `59 (58 from 0)` and signed it by `x` at first and `y` at end of value. You can see this in `Giai5`

```
//This is expected result
//Result array with mark of value at needed position

array:32 [▼
  "ID" => "7917"
  "ProvinceCode" => "MB"
  "Create" => "2016-05-18 18:16:26.790"
  "DayOfTheWeek" => "4"
  "Giai1" => "28192"
  "Giai2" => "83509"
  "Giai3" => "51911-02858"
  "Giai4" => "14102-97270-96025-08465-89047-45904"
  "Giai5" => "7892-9140-x4y069-8499"
  "Giai6" => "6117-7471-5541-9119-4855-0566"
  "Giai7" => "843-860-023"
  "Giai8" => "71-13-55-89"
  "Giai9" => ""
  "Status" => "1"
]
```

from 1 to 50 it works fine, but after position 50, the value of position I get is always wrong

Any idea?

Comment: what is the point of this - how you will use these markers?

Comment: @splash58 It's hard to tell you why do I need that, but I need that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly this time, you can do something like this:

```
$array = [
    "ID" => "7917",
    "ProvinceCode" => "MB",
    "Create" => "2016-05-18 18:16:26.790",
    "DayOfTheWeek" => "4",
    "Giai1" => "28192",
    "Giai2" => "83509",
    "Giai3" => "51911-02858",
    "Giai4" => "14102-97270-96025-08465-89047-45904",
    "Giai5" => "7892-9140-4069-8499",
    "Giai6" => "6117-7471-5541-9119-4855-0566",
    "Giai7" => "843-860-023",
    "Giai8" => "71-13-55-89",
    "Giai9" => "",
    "Status" => "1"
];

$position = 59;

$start = 0;
$end = 0;

foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
    if (!preg_match('/Giai/', $key)) {
        continue;    
    }

    $start = $end + 1;
    $end = $start + strlen(str_replace('-', '', $value)) - 1;

    if (($start <= $position) && ($position <= $end)) {
        $counter = $start;
        $value = str_split($value);

        foreach ($value as &$char) {
            if ($char === '-') {
                continue;
            }

            if ($counter === $position) {
                $char = "x{$char}y";
                break;
            }

            $counter++;
        }

        $value = join($value);
    }
}

var_dump($array);
```

Here is [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13c6862f074e3d13402bf845a5a003d46e692bf9).

The code is a bit lengthy, but this is due to the fact that when you watch for the position you skip the dashes (`-`), but when you need to mark the character you have to take them into account. From this code you can understand the algorithm and then refactor code the way you want. I would suggest to **escape from nested loops**, as **they are hard to read**. You can do this by **breaking code into functions or use the available array functions**.

Comment: I can find the block of position (What is the block `Giai` contains needed value according to position), but important thing is the math to calculate for extractly position of value in this block, mark this value and return it with the original array with the marked value.

Comment: If you find value at position `59` count from `Giai1 to Giai8` is in `Giai5` and some how you can found extractly value is `4 (example)` and you marked it by `x4y` and update `array['Giai5']` with this mark. If only found what key contains value by position, I will not posted here.

Comment: It works, you're my hero, but please change to index for me, from 0 not from 1

Comment: I thought this is expected behavior as we talking about the **position** here **not  index**.

Comment: My fault, I was understand position and index are the same.

Comment: If you want to to go with **indexes**, just set `$end` variable initially like this `$end = -1;`, instead of `$end = 0;`.

Comment: @vietnguyen09, I am glad to help.

Comment: Last question, I don't see you update array, why its update it self?

Comment: If you see `foreach ($array as $key => &$value)`, there is a `&`, that indicates passing [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to the variable, instead of copy. This way when I change the value of that variable it is changed in the main array, which I referenced it from.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple `array_grep()` to fetch all the "Giai" keys and `implode` to concatenate the values to one big string, then selecting a position of that string.

```
$giai = array_flip(preg_grep("/^Giai\d+$/", array_flip($a)));
echo implode("",$giai)[$pos];
```

https://eval.in/573746

Comment: I can get the value, but the thing I can't do is marked found value and keep that array format.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by *"marked found value and keep that array format"*. How do you want to mark the found value?